# Графики на сайт

Tags: диаграммы

подскажите, нашел на данном сайте графики https://xenium.pro/xenium-roi-charts.html,  где можно взять такие же?

Comment: С этого самого сайта и взять. В исходном коде сайта написано, что это Aimy Charts

Comment: @andreymal а если мой сайт не на джумле, то можно их как-то добавить?

Answer (score 0):

У бутстрепа есть похожие графики: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/charts/

А если нужны именно AimyCharts (как на этом сайте): http://www.tourisme-durable.org/media/plg_aimycharts/ или https://xenium.pro/media/plg_aimycharts/aimycharts.js (это один и тот же скрипт)